# Windows Task Scheduler behavior with daily trigger and hourly repeat with indefinite duration

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I've created a trigger as follows:

[image]

It will run this task every day at midnight, and then repeat the task every 1 hour indefinitely.

What is the behavior of this? I'm worried that every day a new task will be triggered and it will overlap with the "indefinitely repeated" tasks from previous days.

Is Task Scheduler smart enough to not have these "indefinitely repeated" tasks compound as time goes on and appropriately reset them when the original task is triggered every day at midnight?

Comment: It doesn’t make any sense to do that. Set it for a duration of “24 hours” and be done with it. Why even take a chance.

Comment: Task will not reset itself every day to execute indefinitely repeat action. But for detail information, we might try to use Event Viewer to monitor the exact action of this task.